# Deleting defunct protected files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I just migrated my Windows 7 installation from a 120GB SSD to a new 500GB SSD.  To do this I used [this program](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/migrate-OS-to-SSD/) to clone the original SSD partition(s) onto the new disk, while increasing the size of the primary OS partition.  That all worked as advertised.

The problem is that now I'm trying to reclaim some space on the 120GB SSD (it's going to be my default game-install volume now).  Specifically, I'm trying to delete all of the things under `/Program Files` and `/Program Files (x86)`.  I've claimed ownership of these folders (and everything in them) using [these instructions](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-how-to-delete-files-protected-by-trustedinstaller/).  And for good measure I've also given "Full Control" over the folders to 'Everyone'.

However, when I attempt to delete the contents of the old 'Program Files' folders, several Microsoft-specific things are left in there.  Attempting to delete any of those gives the following error:

[image]

I *am* an Administrator, and I *did* click to give permission when it asked me.  It still refuses to delete these files off of the old SSD.

Is there any way to force Windows to get rid of these things?  Perferably without having to boot into another OS to do so?

Comment: I am about to get on a train so can't leave an answer but use a search engine to find out how to change ownership in Windows 7. Read up on it first though before doing it

Comment: @Dave - Yep, did that already.  That let me get rid of most of stuff in there.  Basically everything except for folders like 'Internet Explorer', 'Microsoft Games', and so on.  Those folders appear to be special (subject to an extra layer of protection, or something), and _even taking ownership of them is not sufficient to delete them_.  If it was, this question wouldn't be here.

Comment: why not just move off the files you want, and reformat?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Brute force, then?  Yes, that's a workable option.  Though it's (or at least, it _should_ be) more straightforward to just delete the stuff I don't want.  In any case, still think a non-nuclear solution would be a useful thing to have.

Comment: If you don't want these files, then using a live linux environment would allow you to delete them, another solution would be to log into the default Administrator group and delete the files from there.

Comment: You can also use Disk Cleanup>Clean up system files to gain space